# Mongodb, getIndexes. Zero in 'key'

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Here is the output of "getIndexes" command in the mongodb shell:

```
db.users.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "online" : 1,
            "region" : 1,
            "status" : 0
        },
        "ns" : "Pr.users",
        "name" : "online_1_region_1_status_-1"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "birthdate" : 1,
            "status" : 1,
            "region" : 1,
            "sex" : 1,
            "profile.uptime" : -1
        },
        "ns" : "Pr.users",
        "name" : "birthdate_1_status_1_region_1_sex_1_profile.uptime_-1"
    }
]
```

What does it mean "0" in "key" values?
In docs (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/) there are only "1" and "-1".

> system.indexes.key
>
> Contains a document holding the keys held in the index, and the order of the index. Indexes may be either descending or ascending order. A value of negative one (e.g. -1) indicates an index sorted in descending order while a positive value (e.g. 1) indicates an index sorted in an ascending order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this is undefined behavior. Judging by examples below, mongo gets really confused with index value direction set to 0.

## Simple tests:

### Descending index

```
db.test.ensureIndex({t : 1})
```

Let's see used cursors when sorting test collection by field 't'

```
db.test.find.sort({t : 1}).explain()
```

Used cursor: `"cursor" : "BtreeCursor t_1"`

```
db.test.find.sort({t : -1}).explain()
```

Used cursor: `"cursor" : "BtreeCursor t_1 reverse"`

This is expected behavior.

### Ascending index

```
db.test.ensureIndex({t : -1})
```

-

```
db.test.find.sort({t : 1}).explain()
```

Used cursor: `"cursor" : "BtreeCursor t_-1 reverse"`

```
db.test.find.sort({t : -1}).explain()
```

Used cursor: `"cursor" : "BtreeCursor t_-1"`

This is expected behavior as well.

### Index 0

```
db.test.ensureIndex({t : 0})
```

-

```
db.test.find.sort({t : 1}).explain()
```

Used cursor: `"cursor" : "BtreeCursor t_0 reverse"`

```
db.test.find.sort({t : -1}).explain()
```

Used cursor: `"cursor" : "BtreeCursor t_0 reverse"`

For both sorting directions mongo is using reverse cursor.

Not sure why mongo is not handling things like that. Even simple paragraph in documentation would be enough.

Funny thing, you can even set string as index direction.

```
{
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "t" : "sjdhfsdfsdf"
        },
        "ns" : "playground.test",
        "name" : "t_"
    }
```

Or things like this:

```
db.test.ensureIndex({t: ObjectId()}, {additionalParam : "dfsdf"})
...
{
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "t" : ObjectId("51527ebaa845a81ea8434d69")
        },
        "ns" : "playground.test",
        "name" : "t_",
        "additionalParam" : "dfsdf"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for research! I have tested search by field with index with zero: `db.test.find({t:50}).explain()`. It uses that index: "n" = "nscannedObjects" = "nscanned" = 1. 

So I guess indexes with "0" are used for equality tests and doesn't  used for range and sort.